# Getting incorrect syntax on union on combining two results from single table

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I want to combine 2 results from a single table but getting incorrect syntax near `union all`.

```
SELECT  
    ID as 'ABC','1' as 'PQR','2' as 'XYZ', Total as 'LMN'
FROM 
    Employee 
ORDER BY 
    ID

UNION ALL

SELECT  
    ID as 'ABC','1' as 'PQR','2' as 'XYZ', Total as 'LMN'
FROM 
    Employee 
ORDER BY 
    ID
```

But above query fails with the error

> Incorrect syntax near union

**Note**: I have used union all because I don't want to remove duplicate rows.

Comment: Remove the first `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the first `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT
    ID AS 'ABC',
    '1' AS 'PQR',
    '2' AS 'XYZ',
    Total AS 'LMN'
FROM Employee
UNION ALL
SELECT
    ID AS 'ABC',
    '1' AS 'PQR',
    '2' AS 'XYZ',
    Total AS 'LMN'
FROM Employee
ORDER BY ID
```

Example F of the [`UNION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) documentation says:

> When any `SELECT` statement in a `UNION` statement includes an `ORDER BY`
>   clause, that clause should be placed after all `SELECT` statements.

Comment: when i do this union all what happens is my Id gets repeated for this 2nd result set.So what i want is in this second query of union i want all my Id to be different.How can i do this??

Answer (score 2):

Remove the order by from the first part of the Union

Comment: Your welcome, and sorry for short answer, glad I was able to help.